# Spring/Angular: Define request mapping with Angular

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

Using Angular for UI and Spring in the backend secured with Spring security. Is it possible to define view page in the angularjs for request-mapping? For snippet below, on successful authentication, the page redirects to "/display" . Then, in the Spring controller I need to add a mapping for "/display" which returns the view "display"(html). Is it possible to include the mapping in the angular instead of spring??

```
 $scope.login = function() {

      authenticateUser($scope.credentials, function() {

          if ($rootScope.authenticated) {

          $location.path("/display");
          $scope.error = false;

        } else {

          $location.path("/");
          $scope.error = true;
        }

      });
  };
```

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ very cool article. Explains 'classic' security vs 'one page site' security, etc.

Comment: You could use an Angular Controller for that redirection.